# I want to wrap an excel formula that returns an array of values so it replaces 0 values with NA()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reuters

I have a formula that I am using in excel. The formula returns an array of values in the form of a column. I only know how to use an IF statement on a cell or a formula that returns one cell. However, I don't know how to apply it to get it to replace all the 0 values by NA() in the array returned by the formula. I want to wrap the formula using the IF statement.

It is a Reuters formula : =IF(RData(D17:D26;H16) = 0; NA(); RData(D17:D26;H16)), but it does not work at all.

RData(D17:D26;H16) returns the following column

H16 contains: AST_SWPSPD

D17:D26 contains the following RIC Codes:

```
BMPS2YEUAM=R 
BMPS3YEUAM=R 
BMPS4YEUAM=R 
BMPS5YEUAM=R
BMPS7YEUAM=R 
BMPS10YEUAM=R 
BMPS20YEUAM=R 
BMPS30YEUAM=R
```

The resulting column is the following

```
201.7
499.5
389.2
470.6
306.8
0
0
525.3
525.3
525.3
```

I want to get rid of the zeros and replace them with NA
Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping an IF around the formula? Also: What formula? And please add some sample data and desired results...

Comment: Sorry, I did not provide enough information. I tried wrapping in around the formula. It is a Reuters formula : =IF(RData(D17:D26;H16) = 0; NA(); RData(D17:D26;H16)), but it does not work at all.

Answer (score 3):

It should be exactly the same. Lets pretend your formula is `F` (but it would be much better if you added your actual formula or something similar to your question)

```
=IF(F=0, NA(), F)
```

Will work even if `F` is returning an array. Just replace `F` with your entire formula and don't forget to press ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Sorry, I did not provide enough information. I tried wrapping in around the formula. It is a Reuters formula : =IF(RData(D17:D26;H16) = 0; NA(); RData(D17:D26;H16)), but it does not work at all.

Comment: @Helios Judging by the edit on your question Dan's answer should work. Try testing it with something like `{=IF({1,2,3,4,5}=3,NA(),{1,2,3,4,5})}` which will replace the `3` with `#N/A`.

Comment: It actually works that way as well for me but not with the formula. There is a way to go around it though.

Comment: Why do you use ; instead of ,? Is that a locale thing?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your input,

I found a way to go around it, simply by returning one value at a time and wrapping it with the IF statement.

So it becomes: =IF(RData(D17;$H$16)=0;NA(); RData(D17;$H$16))

I am fixing H16 because it contains the argument needed for the formula.

This way it works.

Comment: If you managed to solve your own problem then you should mark this as the correct answer so people know it's solved

Comment: actually, this is only a way to go around it, not really THE solution because I still do not understand how to apply the formula to a range and wrap it to return what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `=IF(RData(D17;$H$16)=0;NA(); RData(D17;$H$16))` you can also use

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(RData(D17;$H$16)));NA())
```

This way, your function gets only called once, which will reduce calculation time.